# How to get Releases Pipelines pre-deployment gates status through REST API in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using Azure DevOps (ADO) REST APIs to build dashboards on Power BI. I wanted to query whether the releases pipelines of all projects in my organization have pre-deployment gates of "SonarCloud Quality Gate status" by using the REST APIs invocation.

I have tried this API (Releases - List) `GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.1`. I am reading the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#gatestatus) and thought this particular `GateStatus`will be useful for my needs, but this `GateStatus` does not show up when I am testing on my pipelines that have pre-deployment gates of "SonarCloud Quality Gate status" configured.

I found this API (Release - Get Release) `GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=5.1`  with [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). That `preDeploymentGates` shows the information I want when I am testing in POSTMAN. But, the problem is it requires `releaseId` in each query which is troublesome for me since my ultimate goal is to have a list of ALL releases in multiple projects of multiple organizations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> since my ultimate goal is to have a list of ALL releases in multiple projects of multiple organizations.

Since you want to get the Pipelines pre-deployment gates status for **ALL** releases in **multiple projects** of **multiple organizations**, so we use the API `(Release - Get Release)` to get the gates status, then loop this API in the **all Release pipelines** in **one** project, next, loop the **all projects** in **one ORG**, latest, loop **all ORGs**.

**First**, We need to create a **All accessible organization** PAT:

[image]

Because we need access multiple organizations.

Second, set a array to store the multiple organization names:

```
$ORGNames=@("Organization1","Organization2")
```

Then using following powershell scripts to loop the API `(Release - Get Release)`:

```
$connectionToken="PAT"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$ORGNames=@("Organization1","Organization2")


ForEach ($ORGName in $ORGNames[0,1])

{

$ProjectUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$($ORGName)/_apis/projects?api-version=5.1" 

Write-Host "URL: $ProjectUrl"

$Projects = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ProjectUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})

$ProjectId = $projects.value.id


Write-Host "Projects = $ProjectId"



    ForEach ($Pt in $ProjectId)

    {

    $baseUrl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$($ORGName)/$($Pt)/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.1"                   
    $ReleaseId = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})
    $ReleaseIds = $ReleaseId.value.id

    Write-Host "ReleaseID = $ReleaseId"



        foreach($ReleaseID in $ReleaseIds){

        $url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$($ORGName)/$($Pt)/_apis/release/releases/$($ReleaseID)?api-version=5.1"

        $GatesStatus = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})

        Write-Host "GatesStatus For ORGName $ORGName Project $Pt And Release ID $ReleaseID= $($GatesStatus.environments.deploySteps.preDeploymentGates.status | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

         }
      }

   }
```

The test result:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: i actually did it in Power BI so didnt use the Powershell script. but thanks for the reference. ultimately what i did was merging two queries, making each of the API as a function in Power BI (having release ID as parameter of the function) then merge them into 1 query